Simple DiffSharp example
How to convert this simple PyTorch snippet to DiffSharp? It's supposed to be similar but many functions are not to be found.
# Define tensors with requires_grad=True to track computation history
x = torch.tensor(2.0, requires_grad=True)
y = torch.tensor(3.0, requires_grad=True)
 
# Perform a computation
z = x**2 + y**3
print("Output tensor z:", z)
 
# Compute gradients
z.backward()
print("Gradient of x:", x.grad)
print("Gradient of y:", y.grad)


DiffSharp is based on TorchSharp, which I think is more mature (but still quite flaky in places, especially when called from F#). Here is your example in TorchSharp instead:
open TorchSharp

let ( ** ) (a : torch.Tensor) (b : float) =
    a.pow(b.ToScalar())

// Define tensors with requires_grad=True to track computation history
let x = torch.tensor(2.0, requires_grad=true)
let y = torch.tensor(3.0, requires_grad=true)
 
// Perform a computation
let z = x ** 2 + y ** 3
printfn $"Output tensor z: {z.item<float>()}"
 
// Compute gradients
z.backward()
printfn $"Gradient of x: {x.item<float>()}"
printfn $"Gradient of y: {y.item<float>()}"

Output:
Output tensor z: 31
Gradient of x: 2
Gradient of y: 3

